# Counting down a variable length array of integers to Zero in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, counter

I have an array that contains the total number of lines in 3 files. Example: [3,4,5]. I would like to produce a sequence of numbers that count that array down to zero in a methodical way giving me every combination of lines in the three files. This example uses 3 files/length-3 array, but the algorithm should be able to work an array with any arbitrary length.

For the example above, the solution would look like:

```
[3,4,5]  (line 3 from file 1, line 4 from file 2, line 5 from file 3)  
[3,4,4]  
[3,4,3]  
[3,4,2]  
[3,4,1]  
[3,4,0]  
[3,3,5]  
[3,3,4]  
[3,3,3]  
[3,3,2]
```

and so on...

My first attempt at producing an algorithm for this recursively decrements a position in the array, and when that position reaches zero - decrements the position before it. However I'm not able to keep the decrementing going for farther than the last two positions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

    public class FilePositionGenerator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] starterArray = {2, 2, 2};
            int[] counters = starterArray.clone();
            List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            FilePositionGenerator f = new FilePositionGenerator();
            f.generateFilePositions(starterArray, counters, (starterArray.length - 1), results);
        }//end main

        void generateFilePositions(int[] originalArray, int[] modifiedArray, int counterPosition, List<Integer> results) {

            if (modifiedArray[counterPosition] == 0 && counterPosition > 0) {
                modifiedArray[counterPosition] = originalArray[counterPosition];
                counterPosition = counterPosition - 1;
            } else {
                modifiedArray[counterPosition] = modifiedArray[counterPosition] - 1;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(modifiedArray));
                generateFilePositions(originalArray, modifiedArray, counterPosition, results);
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that to deal with a variable length array, the algorithm must be recursive, but I'm having trouble thinking it through. So I decided to try a different approach.

My second attempt at producing an algorithm uses a dual pointer method that keeps a pointer on the current countdown position[the rightmost position], and a pointer to the next non-rightmost position(pivotPointer) that will be decremented when the rightmost position reaches zero. Like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class DualPointer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] counters = {2, 2, 2}; // initialize the problem set
        int[] original = {2, 2, 2}; // clone a copy to reset the problem array
        int[] stopConditionArray = {0, 0, 0};   // initialize an object to show what the stopCondition should be
        int pivotLocation = counters.length - 1;    // pointer that starts at the right, and moves left
        int counterLocation = counters.length - 1;  // pointer that always points to the rightmost position
        boolean stopCondition = false;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counters));
        while (stopCondition == false) {

            if (pivotLocation >= 0 && counterLocation >= 0 && counters[counterLocation] > 0) {
                // decrement the rightmost position
                counters[counterLocation] = counters[counterLocation] - 1;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counters));
            } else if (pivotLocation >= 0 && counters[counterLocation] <= 0) {
                // the rightmost position has reached zero, so check the pivotPointer
                // and decrement if necessary, or move pointer to the left
                if (counters[pivotLocation] == 0) {
                    counters[pivotLocation] = original[pivotLocation];
                    pivotLocation--;
                }
                counters[pivotLocation] = counters[pivotLocation] - 1;
                counters[counterLocation] = original[counterLocation]; // reset the rightmost position
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counters));
            } else if (Arrays.equals(counters, stopConditionArray)) {
                // check if we have reached the solution
                stopCondition = true;
            } else {
                // emergency breakout of infinite loop
                stopCondition = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Upon running, you can see 2 obvious problems:

```
[2, 2, 2]  
[2, 2, 1]  
[2, 2, 0]  
[2, 1, 2]  
[2, 1, 1]  
[2, 1, 0]  
[2, 0, 2]  
[2, 0, 1]  
[2, 0, 0]  
[1, 2, 2]  
[1, 2, 1]  
[1, 2, 0]  
[0, 2, 2]  
[0, 2, 1]  
[0, 2, 0]
```

Number one, the pivotPointer does not decrement properly when the pivotPointer and currentCountdown are more than one array cell apart. Secondly, there is an arrayIndexOutOfBounds at the line `counters[pivotLocation] = counters[pivotLocation] - 1;` that if fixed,
breaks the algorithm from running properly alltogether.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest a different approach.

The idea in recursion is to reduce the size of the problem in each recursive call, until you reach a trivial case, in which you don't have to make another recursive call.

When you first call the recursive method for an array of n elements, you can iterate in a loop over the range of values of the last index (n-1), make a recursive call to generate all the combinations for the array of the first n-1  elements, and combine the outputs.

Here's some partial Java/ partial pseudo code :

The first call :

```
List<int[]> output = generateCombinations(inputArray,inputArray.length);
```

The recursive method `List<int[]> generateCombinations(int[] array, int length)` :

```
List<int[]> output = new ArrayList<int[]>();
if length == 0 
    // the end of the recursion
    for (int i = array[length]; i>=0; i--)
        output.add (i)
else
    // the recursive step
    List<int[]> partialOutput = generateCombinations(array, length - 1)
    for (int i = array[length]; i>=0; i--)
        for (int[] arr : partialOutput)
            output.add(arr + i)
return output
```

The recursive method returns a `List<int[]>`. This means that in "output.add (i)" you should create an int array with a single element and add it to the list, while in `output.add(arr + i)` you'll create an array of arr.length+1 elements, and copy to it the elements of arr followed by i.

Answer (score 0):

The fun thing about recursion is that you can have it do exactly what you want it to. In this case, for each number at index `i` of your array of counts, we want to combine it with each number at index `i + 1` until we reach the end of the array. The trick is not to return to index `i` once you've run through all the options for it.

JavaScript code:

```js
var arr = [3,4,5];
var n = arr.length;

function f(cs,i){
  // base case
  if (i == n){
    console.log(cs.join(','));
    return;
  }

  // otherwise
  while (cs[i] >= 0){
    // copy counts
    _cs = cs.slice();

    // recurse
    f(_cs,i + 1);

    // change number at index i
    cs[i]--;
  }
}

f(arr,0);
```